# How to make an action running by default when users access the system

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, action

I want to make an action running by default when users access my web site.

This is a classic `Java EE` project that is developed with `Struts2` and `Tomcat`. I know how to do this in web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

But, I want to do this through Struts2's action.

Comment: Use `response.sendRedirect` in your `index.jsp` or you can do a trick with empty file and action with the same name.

Comment: There's default action concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code and see if this works.

```
 <action name="index" class="myaction">
     <result>/index.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

And you can also try this.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/myfolder/index.action</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

another way is in your index jsp is you do something like this

```
<% response.sendRedirect("home.do"); %>
```

but I don't believe that this an appropriate approach

Comment: ... You'd also need to map the welcome file to the action, configure the container to allow filtered resources as welcome files if necessary, etc. You can also just redirect in index.jsp to an action.

Comment: @Dave Newton Thanks for the heads up! I was just wondering though, why  did struts2 did not provide any welcome-file-action. or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the `default-action-ref` tag to indicate the default action to invoke when a request is made that doesn't map to any actions.

```
<default-action-ref name="home"/>

<action name="home" class="myaction">
  <result>/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp</result>
</action>
```